# Make a dictionary in Python from arg list

Tags: python

I want to take create a dictionary from `arg_list`:

```
arg_list = "--config=pools_issuance.config --current_mm=9 --current_yy=15 --agency_id='FH'"
```

E.g:

```
input = {}

for arg in arg_list:
   x = arg.split(' --')
   input[x[0]] = x[0]
```

This isn't working and gives me:

```
{' ': ' ',
 "'": "'",
 '-': '-',
 '.': '.',
 '1': '1',
 '5': '5',
 '9': '9',
 '=': '=',
 'F': 'F',
 'H': 'H',
 '_': '_',
 'a': 'a',
  ...
 'y': 'y'}
```

I don't understand why.

Comment: Why are you not using an actual argument parser?

Comment: See the standard [**`argparse`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library.

Comment: Why you throw away @Avinash Raj 's edit...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the standard [**`argparse`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library

However, if you don't want to, read on.

```
>>> arg_list = "--config=pools_issuance.config --current_mm=9 --current_yy=15 --agency_id='FH'"
```

Your main problem is that you iterate over every character in the string:

```
>>> for arg in arg_list:
...     print arg
-
-
c
o
n
f
i
...
```

We can split the string based on whitespace:

```
>>> arg_list.split()
['--config=pools_issuance.config',
 '--current_mm=9',
 '--current_yy=15',
 "--agency_id='FH'"]
```

Then for each argument strip the '--', and split on `'='` to get the key value pairs:

```
>>> [arg.strip('--').split('=') for arg in arg_list.split()]
[['config', 'pools_issuance.config'],
 ['current_mm', '9'],
 ['current_yy', '15'],
 ['agency_id', "'FH'"]]
```

Then pass them to a dictionary constructor:

```
>>> dict(arg.strip('--').split('=')
...      for arg in arg_list.split())
{'agency_id': "'FH'",
 'config': 'pools_issuance.config',
 'current_mm': '9',
 'current_yy': '15'}
```

You might want to clean up some of the values as the numbers will be strings, and the `agency_id` will be a string with the quotes included: `"'FH'"`